# Is there any setting like "adjustViewBounds" on Smartface?

Tags: smartface.io

I have a lot of pictures with different width and height.

I want to set a list, with 100% width and dynamic height images but i cant find any setting like "adjustViewBounds" on Smartface.

My images have different width so autosize "image size property" not for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use repeatbox and wants to change rowHeights related to image sizes, you can use customRowHeight method for repeatBox.

like ;

```
var rBox = new SMF.UI.Repeatbox();
 // adding items to repeatbox
 /* If this property is assigned to a function, this function will be called. This function results will override any height value previously given
 * @param {number} maxRows  Required. Maximum value index of rows to be added to repeatbox
 * @param {number} minRows  Optional. Minimum value index of rows to be added to repeatbox
 * @return {object} A custom object with two key properties (activeItem , inactiveitem) which values are number arrays
  */
 rbox.customRowHeight = function (maxRows, minRows) {
    var i;
    var result = {
        activeItem : [],
        item: []
    };
    for (i = minRows or  0; //Default value if minRows is not provided
        i < maxRows; i++) {
        switch (i) {
        case 0:
            result.activeItem[i] = result.item[i] = "50dp";
            break;
        case (i <= 10 and i > 0):
            result.activeItem[i] = "40dp";
            result.itemtem[i] = "35dp";
            break;
        default:
            result.activeItem[i] = result.item[i] = 30;
        }
    }
    return result;
 };
```

In addition to this, you can create a ScrollView and you can fill it with your images dynamically. You can set its layout as linear than you can set the autoSize feature of ScrollView as true. With this way, you can have a dynamic height for ScrollView and you can add them row by row into the scrollView.

For more information about Layouts : http://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/controls/layouts/

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to use this list for repeatbox row or for what? Dynamically, you can set image height and image width which is in any page.

Comment: i want to use this pics in a repeatbox but i can't find any settings for dynamic height or width.